# Can the Pearson's correlation coefficient be calculated on a linear-log ggplot without being impacted by the log scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Hello and welcome to my question.

**What I want** is to plot data from two columns as a linear-log scatterplot and then calculate the Pearson's correlation coefficient using the `ggpubr::stat_cor()` function. The coefficient needs to be calculated on the plot, since the analysis will involve a lot of exploration; calculating separately would be laborious.

**Example Dataset**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

df <- tibble(A = c(1:10), B = c(1:10))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = A, y = B)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_cor(aes(label = ..r.label..), method = "pearson") +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

**The issue** is that, while I can run this code *without* the `scale_x_continuous()` and get what I expect (*R* = 1), I need the x-axis to be in log scale in my actual code. When I add the log scale, `stat_cor()` calculates the coefficient with the log values, resulting in an unexpected correlation (*R* = 0.95).

[image: Not what I want]

**The bottom line** is that I'd like a solution that allows me to plot the x-axis on a log scale without impacting the `stat_cor()` function, so that the function calculates the coefficient on the original (linear) values.

Comment: 1) I think it's worth considering that this may be confusing to people reading your plot. 2) `ggpubr` is convenient, but you pay in flexibility. You can compute the correlation easily outside of ggplot and then put it on your plot with `geom_text` or `annotate`. 3) You could try using `coord_trans(y = 'log10')`, which will only affect the visual appearance of your points and not alter the underlying scales, but your plot will look a bit different.

Comment: @Axeman, thanks for reminding me of ```coord_trans()```; it works for this problem. I agree plotting log but showing a linear stat is confusing, but this is one of those times that I don't have 100% control of my product and need to meet (somewhat arbitrary) expectations. Also, I'll probably do what you suggested and calculate the stat separately for the final version, but I need this flexibility for the exploration phase.